# Find the coefficient polynomials $Q_k(x)$ of $T$ in the representation $T = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} Q_k(x)D^k$.

Tags: operator-theory

Given that the anti-differentiation $T : \mathbb{R}[x] \to \mathbb{R}[x] $ is a linear operator. Find the coefficient polynomials $Q_k(x)$ of 
$T$ in the representation $T = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} Q_k(x)D^k$.

I figure I may have to use induction but not sure how to put it together 
Let 
$Q_0(x)=T[1]$ repeat for $Q_1(x), \cdots, Q_{n-1}(x)$ then set

$Q_n(x)= \frac{1}{n!}\left(T[x^n]- \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}Q_k(x)D^k[x^n] \right)$

Now then somehow show that this will agree with $T$ on every polynomial $p \in \mathbb{R}[x]$

Comment: what does it mean that $T$ is an anti-differentiation?

Comment: The operation of anti-differentiation, so $T$ is the linear operator for anti-differentiation

Comment: How did you come up with $Q_n(x)$? (If you did it yourself, do you understand why $T$ agrees with the sum on $1,x,x^2,...$?)

Comment: That was part of the hint not really sure why $T$ agrees